# MySQL UPDATE Statement Fails From A Sub Query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sql-update

I have some stupid mistake. I want to update some table using this stored procedure statement.

The logic is: update table x where the rows originally from select statement.

This stored procedure always fails:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `sre`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_generateGraphicsAcc`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_generateGraphicsAcc`(IN sa INT, IN thn VARCHAR(12), IN acc VARCHAR(12))
BEGIN
/*tmp_totalpesan.type_m = 1*/
/*first, update tmp_totalpesan to empty row(s)*/
UPDATE tmp_totalpesan SET totalpesan = '' WHERE type_m = 1;
/*second, update tmp_totalpesan from select statement.*/
UPDATE tmp_totalpesan tt
   SET (tt.totalpesan = 
        SELECT COUNT(mp.quantity)
        FROM mt_pesanan mp
        WHERE (mp.ms_salesarea_idms_salesarea = sa )
        AND (mp.tahun = thn)
        AND (check_aksesoris_barang(mp.ms_langganan_idms_kodebarang) = acc)
        AND tt.bulan = alter_monthname(MONTHNAME(mp.tgl_pesan))
    GROUP BY mp.bulan)
WHERE type_m = 1;       
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

the error is shown up

`Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(tt.totalpesan =           SELECT COUNT(mp.quantity)    FROM mt_pesanan mp    WH' at line 8`

Can you see where the problem is?
Thanks.

**UPDATE**

what this stored procedure want to achieve is:

let say i have 1 tables it is transaction table and i want to generate result from specific parameter.

the result from SELECT bla bla bla using this query:

```
 SELECT COUNT(mp.quantity), alter_monthname(MONTHNAME(tgl_pesan))
 FROM mt_pesanan mp
 WHERE (mp.ms_salesarea_idms_salesarea = sa )
 AND (mp.tahun = thn)
 AND (check_aksesoris_barang(mp.ms_langganan_idms_kodebarang) = acc)
 GROUP BY mp.bulan;
```

the result is

- `month - value`
- `JANUARY - 1566`
- `FEBRUARY - 800`

and so on... (12 rows)

what i want is update the second table with value (1566, 800,etc..) from the select statement in the result.

The same column name is the month from select statement corresponding to the other table.

how to achieve this?

actually the problem

Comment: You should have no `()` around the `column = value` in the `SET` clause. Remove the `()` from `SET (tt.totalpesan = SELECT....)`

Comment: How does tt relate to mp?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yes, it shows up the error. i have done this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parentheses are not aligned correctly.  Do you mean this?

```
UPDATE tmp_totalpesan tt
   SET tt.totalpesan = 
        (SELECT COUNT(mp.quantity)
         FROM mt_pesanan mp
         WHERE (mp.ms_salesarea_idms_salesarea = sa )
         AND (mp.tahun = thn)
         AND (check_aksesoris_barang(mp.ms_langganan_idms_kodebarang) = acc)
         AND tt.bulan = alter_monthname(MONTHNAME(mp.tgl_pesan))
         GROUP BY mp.bulan
        );
```

My problem with this is the `group by`.  This subquery could return multiple rows, which will generate an error.  If the `where` clause selects the rows you want to summarize, then you don't need the `group by`.  Also, normally with a column called `quantity`, I would expect `sum()` or `avg()`, but not `count()`.  Are you sure the `count()` is cwhat you really want?

EDIT:

I think your query is correct without the `group by`.  You are already correlating the month in `tt` to the month in the subquery:

```
UPDATE tmp_totalpesan tt
   SET tt.totalpesan = 
        (SELECT COUNT(mp.quantity)
         FROM mt_pesanan mp
         WHERE (mp.ms_salesarea_idms_salesarea = sa )
         AND (mp.tahun = thn)
         AND (check_aksesoris_barang(mp.ms_langganan_idms_kodebarang) = acc)
         AND tt.bulan = alter_monthname(MONTHNAME(mp.tgl_pesan))
        );
```

However, you might want to add the following in the subquery:

```
tt.bulan = mp.bulan
```

Comment: yes the problem is the (). and you are right too, the group by function is failing the logic. I have a problem to UPDATE table-X from where the source of column is in table Y. @Gordon Linoff, please see the UPDATED section

Comment: where i place the `tt.bulan = mp.bulan`? outside the subquery or in the subquery itself?